# ¿Para que sirve el comando -des -out en linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Quisiera saber para que sirve -des -out, dado a que estoy generando un clave privada para un certificado.  Todo el comando en si es
openssl genrsa -des -out ubuntu.key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, y por las dudas, te recomiendo, cada vez que tengas una duda sobre algún comando en Linux puedes ejecutar en la línea de comandos `man <comando>` por ejemplo `man openssl`, Linux tiene un sistema de ayuda muy bien documentado.

En cuanto a tu pregunta: básicamente dicho comando genera una clave privada, en cuanto a los parámetros:

- `-out`: Establece el nombre del archivo de salida, en tu ejemplo
  `ubuntu.key`
- `-des`: Establece el cifrado de la clave privada con el algoritmo [`DES`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) en el modo cbc.